# Не работает приём/отправка почты на сервере

Tags: сервер, email, ispmanager

Доброго всем времени суток.
Есть выделенный сервер, на котором крутится сайт. Понадобилось прикрутить почтовый сервер. Настраиваю его в панели управления сервером. Создал почтовый домен, и прикрутил к нему почтовый ящик. Всё, вроде бы, правильно. Ошибок не было. Но при отправке письма начинается веселье. При тестировании использовал модули `AfterLogic` и `RoundCube`. Отправляю письмо на свой ящик `my.post@gmail.com`. Отправлено успешно, ошибок нет. Открываю свою почту и жду. Жду минуту, жду две, жду 30 минут. Ничего не приходит. Отправляю письмо со своей гугловской почты на серверную почту `support@domain.com` - всё отправилось, ошибок нет. Но письмо не доходит. В общем, в любую из сторон отправляю письмо - отправляется успешно, но не доходит до цели. Добавил MX-запись (пробовал две разные) в настройках домена у моего регистратора - эффект нулевой.
Не могу понять - в чём проблема? Гуглил, читал офф. доки ISP-менеджера - везде описываются действия, которые я делал ещё до прочтения всей этой инфы. Так что гугл мне не помог. Буду благодарен за подсказку или помощь.
С уважением, intro94.

Конфигурация сервера:

```
ОС: Centos 6.8
ПУ: ISPmanager Lite 5.109.1
```

Домен второго уровня, вида `domain.com` и настроенное SSL-шифрование (сертификаты действительные). Сайт по адресу `domain.com` отлично открывается, всё работает - ошибок никаких.
Ниже скриншоты настроек домена у регистратора, записей домена на сервере, а также настройки почтового домена и ящика на сервере.

[image: Настройки домена у регистратора]
[image: Записи домена на сервере]

[image: Настройки почтового домена]
[image: Настройки почтового ящика]

---

> А вы попробуйте снаружи постучаться на тот сервер куда MX указывает `telnet ip-addres 25` по крайней мере должны увидеть приглашение почтового сервера. можете ему `HELO domain.com` написать, он ответить должен. Если этого не происходит - либо порт не проброшен, либо сервер не поднят, либо фаервол где то заблочил

```
MacBook-Pro-Yuri:~ intro$ telnet domain.com 25
Trying ***.***.***.140...
Connected to domain.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 domain.com ESMTP Exim 4.84_2 Fri, 23 Jun 2017 14:08:56 +0300
HELO World
250 domain.com Hello World [**.**.***.57]
```

Открыл следующие порты:

```
110/tcp  open  pop3
995/tcp  open  pop3s

143/tcp  open  imap
993/tcp  open  imaps

25/tcp   open  smtp
465/tcp  open  smtps

587/tcp  open  submission
```

При попытке достучаться по telnet - ответ получаю только при подключении по обычному соединению. Все подключения к защищённым портам остаются без ответа. Всего 4 обычных и 3 защищённых, получается.

Отправил письмо через AfterLogic сам на себя, ничего не пришло, а в логах `exim`-а словил такое:

```
2017-06-23 15:45:55 1dONyF-0006wq-3y <= support@domain.com H=localhost (domain.com) [127.0.0.1] P=esmtpsa X=TLSv1:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:256 SNI="127.0.0.1" A=auth_login:support@domain.com S=1374 id=05edf799cbfec48956883b230cd0c94b@domain.com from <support@domain.com> for support@domain.com
2017-06-23 15:45:55 no IP address found for host [***]x[***]x[***]x140.static-customer.rostov.ertelecom.ru (during SMTP connection from [***.***.***.140])
2017-06-23 15:45:55 no IP address found for host [***]x[***]x[***]x140.static-customer.rostov.ertelecom.ru (during SMTP connection from [***.***.***.140])
2017-06-23 15:45:55 no IP address found for host [***]x[***]x[***]x140.static-customer.rostov.ertelecom.ru (during SMTP connection from [***.***.***.140])
2017-06-23 15:45:55 H=(domain.com) [***.***.***.140] X=TLSv1.2:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:256 F=<support@domain.com> temporarily rejected RCPT <support@domain.com>: greylisted host ***.***.***.140
2017-06-23 15:45:55 1dONyF-0006wq-3y == support@domain.com R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp defer (-44): SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO:<support@domain.com>: host domain.com [***.***.***.140]: 451 Greylisted, see http://postgrey.schweikert.ch/help/domain.com.html
```

Отключил Greylist, отправил письмо со своей гугловской почты:

```
2017-06-23 15:59:10 1dOOB4-0007nd-Ju DKIM: d=gmail.com s=20161025 c=relaxed/relaxed a=rsa-sha256 [verification succeeded]
2017-06-23 15:59:11 1dOOB4-0007nd-Ju From my.post@gmail.com to support@domain.com X-Spam_score: 2.
2017-06-23 15:59:11 1dOOB4-0007nd-Ju <= my.post@gmail.com H=mail-lf0-f68.google.com [209.85.215.68] P=esmtps X=TLSv1.2:AES128-GCM-SHA256:128 SNI="domain.com" S=3828 id=CALfLqBrnx6S-YriYgkCp8s9NxHosNMDQwax8uptQTWFJbp4hJg@mail.gmail.com from <my.post@gmail.com> for support@domain.com
2017-06-23 15:59:11 no IP address found for host [***]x[***]x[***]x140.static-customer.rostov.ertelecom.ru (during SMTP connection from [***.***.***.140])
2017-06-23 15:59:11 no IP address found for host [***]x[***]x[***]x140.static-customer.rostov.ertelecom.ru (during SMTP connection from [***.***.***.140])
2017-06-23 15:59:11 no IP address found for host [***]x[***]x[***]x140.static-customer.rostov.ertelecom.ru (during SMTP connection from [***.***.***.140])
2017-06-23 15:59:11 1dOOB5-0007no-N4 DKIM: d=gmail.com s=20161025 c=relaxed/relaxed a=rsa-sha256 [verification succeeded]
2017-06-23 15:59:12 1dOOB5-0007no-N4 From my.post@gmail.com to support@domain.com X-Spam_score: 14.
2017-06-23 15:59:12 1dOOB5-0007no-N4 <= my.post@gmail.com H=(domain.com) [***.***.***.140] P=esmtps X=TLSv1.2:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:256 S=5486 id=CALfLqBrnx6S-YriYgkCp8s9NxHosNMDQwax8uptQTWFJbp4hJg@mail.gmail.com from <my.post@gmail.com> for support@domain.com
2017-06-23 15:59:12 1dOOB4-0007nd-Ju => support@domain.com R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp H=domain.com [***.***.***.140] X=TLSv1.2:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:256 DN="/C=XX/ST=XX/L=XX/O=XX/OU=XX/CN=domain.com/emailAddress=root@domain.com" C="250 OK id=1dOOB5-0007no-N4"
2017-06-23 15:59:12 1dOOB4-0007nd-Ju Completed
2017-06-23 15:59:12 no IP address found for host [***]x[***]x[***]x140.static-customer.rostov.ertelecom.ru (during SMTP connection from [***.***.***.140])
2017-06-23 15:59:12 no IP address found for host [***]x[***]x[***]x140.static-customer.rostov.ertelecom.ru (during SMTP connection from [***.***.***.140])
2017-06-23 15:59:12 no IP address found for host [***]x[***]x[***]x140.static-customer.rostov.ertelecom.ru (during SMTP connection from [***.***.***.140])
2017-06-23 15:59:12 1dOOB6-0007ns-42 DKIM: d=gmail.com s=20161025 c=relaxed/relaxed a=rsa-sha256 [verification succeeded]
2017-06-23 15:59:12 1dOOB6-0007ns-42 From my.post@gmail.com to support@domain.com X-Spam_score: 14.
2017-06-23 15:59:12 1dOOB6-0007ns-42 <= my.post@gmail.com H=(domain.com) [***.***.***.140] P=esmtps X=TLSv1.2:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:256 S=7144 id=CALfLqBrnx6S-YriYgkCp8s9NxHosNMDQwax8uptQTWFJbp4hJg@mail.gmail.com from <my.post@gmail.com> for support@domain.com
2017-06-23 15:59:12 1dOOB5-0007no-N4 => support@domain.com R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp H=domain.com [***.***.***.140] X=TLSv1.2:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:256 DN="/C=XX/ST=XX/L=XX/O=XX/OU=XX/CN=domain.com/emailAddress=root@domain.com" C="250 OK id=1dOOB6-0007ns-42"
2017-06-23 15:59:12 1dOOB5-0007no-N4 Completed
2017-06-23 15:59:12 no IP address found for host [***]x[***]x[***]x140.static-customer.rostov.ertelecom.ru (during SMTP connection from [***.***.***.140])
2017-06-23 15:59:12 no IP address found for host [***]x[***]x[***]x140.static-customer.rostov.ertelecom.ru (during SMTP connection from [***.***.***.140])
2017-06-23 15:59:12 no IP address found for host [***]x[***]x[***]x140.static-customer.rostov.ertelecom.ru (during SMTP connection from [***.***.***.140])
```

Со временем в логах появляется такая запись:

```
2017-06-23 16:00:24 1dOOCG-0007u2-0j <= <> R=1dOOCF-0007tb-0t U=exim P=local S=51151 from <> for my.post@gmail.com
2017-06-23 16:00:24 1dOOCG-0007u2-0j gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [2a00:1450:4010:c0f::1a] Network is unreachable
2017-06-23 16:00:24 1dOOCF-0007tb-0t Completed
2017-06-23 16:00:24 1dOOCG-0007u2-0j Remote host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [173.194.221.27] closed connection in response to initial connection
2017-06-23 16:00:24 1dOOCG-0007u2-0j alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [2404:6800:4008:c04::1b] Network is unreachable
2017-06-23 16:00:24 1dOOCG-0007u2-0j Remote host alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [74.125.204.27] closed connection in response to initial connection
2017-06-23 16:00:24 1dOOCG-0007u2-0j == my.post@gmail.com R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp defer (-18): Remote host alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [74.125.204.27] closed connection in response to initial connection
```

Отправил письмо на другую свою почту:

```
2017-06-23 16:11:27 1dOOMx-0000Aw-T8 <= support@domain.com H=localhost (domain.com) [127.0.0.1] P=esmtpa A=auth_plain:support@domain.com S=690 id=044a7b97e6b1ff5b182d447452a3fe8a@domain.com from <support@domain.com> for my.post.2@gmail.com
2017-06-23 16:11:28 1dOOMx-0000Aw-T8 Remote host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [64.233.162.27] closed connection in response to initial connection
2017-06-23 16:11:28 1dOOMx-0000Aw-T8 alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [2404:6800:4008:c04::1a] Network is unreachable
2017-06-23 16:11:28 1dOOMx-0000Aw-T8 Remote host alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [74.125.204.27] closed connection in response to initial connection
2017-06-23 16:11:28 1dOOMx-0000Aw-T8 == my.post.2@gmail.com R=dnslookup T=remote_smtp defer (-18): Remote host alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [74.125.204.27] closed connection in response to initial connection
```

---

В файле `/var/log/maillog` свыше 600 строк вида:

```
Jun 21 12:24:21 domain dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<support@domain.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=28145, secured
Jun 21 12:24:21 domain dovecot: imap(support@domain.com): Disconnected: Logged out bytes=79/762
```

Содержимое файла `/var/log/maillog` с удалёнными вышеупомянутыми строками.

```
Jun 21 12:16:53 domain postgrey[25773]: Process Backgrounded
Jun 21 12:16:53 domain postgrey[25773]: 2017/06/21-12:16:53 postgrey (type Net::Server::Multiplex) starting! pid(25773)
Jun 21 12:16:53 domain postgrey[25773]: Binding to UNIX socket file "/var/spool/postfix/postgrey/socket"
Jun 21 12:16:53 domain postgrey[25773]: Setting gid to "495 495"
Jun 21 12:16:53 domain postgrey[25773]: Setting uid to "495"
Jun 21 12:17:53 domain spamd[26196]: logger: removing stderr method
Jun 21 12:18:14 domain spamd[26198]: spamd: server started on port 783/tcp (running version 3.3.1)
Jun 21 12:18:14 domain spamd[26198]: spamd: server pid: 26198
Jun 21 12:18:14 domain spamd[26198]: spamd: server successfully spawned child process, pid 26275
Jun 21 12:18:14 domain spamd[26198]: spamd: server successfully spawned child process, pid 26276
Jun 21 12:18:14 domain spamd[26198]: prefork: child states: IS
Jun 21 12:18:14 domain spamd[26198]: prefork: child states: II
Jun 21 12:22:44 domain dovecot: master: Warning: SIGHUP received - reloading configuration
Jun 21 12:22:54 domain dovecot: master: Warning: SIGHUP received - reloading configuration
Jun 21 12:23:44 domain dovecot: master: Warning: Processes aren't dying after reload, sending SIGTERM.
Jun 21 12:23:44 domain dovecot: auth: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1884 uid=0 code=kill)
Jun 21 12:23:44 domain dovecot: config: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1884 uid=0 code=kill)
Jun 21 12:23:44 domain dovecot: auth: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1884 uid=0 code=kill)
Jun 21 12:23:54 domain dovecot: master: Warning: Processes aren't dying after reload, sending SIGTERM.
Jun 21 12:23:54 domain dovecot: auth: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1884 uid=0 code=kill)
Jun 21 12:23:54 domain dovecot: config: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1884 uid=0 code=kill)
Jun 21 12:24:07 domain dovecot: master: Warning: SIGHUP received - reloading configuration
Jun 21 12:24:17 domain dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<support@domain.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=28118, secured
Jun 21 12:24:17 domain dovecot: imap(support@domain.com): Disconnected: Logged out bytes=55/666
Jun 21 12:24:21 domain dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<support@domain.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=28134, secured
Jun 21 12:24:21 domain dovecot: imap(support@domain.com): Disconnected: Logged out bytes=318/1419
Jun 21 12:24:21 domain dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<support@domain.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=28138, secured
Jun 21 12:24:21 domain dovecot: imap(support@domain.com): Disconnected: Logged out bytes=79/762
Jun 21 12:24:21 domain dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<support@domain.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=28145, secured
Jun 21 12:24:21 domain dovecot: imap(support@domain.com): Disconnected: Logged out bytes=79/762
Jun 21 12:24:22 domain dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<support@domain.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=28148, secured
Jun 21 12:24:22 domain dovecot: imap(support@domain.com): Disconnected: Logged out bytes=79/762
Jun 21 12:24:22 domain dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<support@domain.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=28151, secured
Jun 21 12:24:22 domain dovecot: imap(support@domain.com): Disconnected: Logged out bytes=55/666
Jun 21 12:24:22 domain dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<support@domain.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=28156, secured
Jun 21 12:24:22 domain dovecot: imap(support@domain.com): Disconnected: Logged out bytes=77/761
Jun 21 12:24:22 domain dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<support@domain.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=28159, secured
Jun 21 12:24:22 domain dovecot: imap(support@domain.com): Disconnected: Logged out bytes=81/763
Jun 21 12:24:22 domain dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<support@domain.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=28162, secured
Jun 21 12:24:22 domain dovecot: imap(support@domain.com): Disconnected: Logged out bytes=77/761
Jun 21 12:24:23 domain dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<support@domain.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=28165, secured
Jun 21 12:24:23 domain dovecot: imap(support@domain.com): Disconnected: Logged out bytes=58/417
Jun 21 12:24:44 domain dovecot: master: Warning: Processes aren't dying after reload, sending SIGTERM.
Jun 21 12:24:44 domain dovecot: log: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1884 uid=0 code=kill)
Jun 21 12:24:54 domain dovecot: master: Warning: Processes aren't dying after reload, sending SIGTERM.
Jun 21 12:24:54 domain dovecot: log: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1884 uid=0 code=kill)
Jun 21 12:25:07 domain dovecot: master: Warning: Processes aren't dying after reload, sending SIGTERM.
Jun 21 12:25:07 domain dovecot: config: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1884 uid=0 code=kill)
Jun 21 12:25:23 domain dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<support@domain.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=28367, secured
Jun 21 12:25:23 domain dovecot: imap(support@domain.com): Disconnected: Logged out bytes=104/493
Jun 21 12:25:44 domain dovecot: master: Warning: SIGHUP received - reloading configuration
Jun 21 12:25:52 domain dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<support@domain.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=28477, secured
Jun 21 12:25:52 domain dovecot: imap(support@domain.com): Disconnected: Logged out bytes=11/340
Jun 21 12:25:54 domain dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<support@domain.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=28484, secured
Jun 21 12:25:54 domain dovecot: imap(support@domain.com): Disconnected: Logged out bytes=80/1034
Jun 21 12:25:54 domain dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<support@domain.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, mpid=28487, secured
Jun 21 12:25:54 domain dovecot: imap(support@domain.com): Disconnected: Logged out bytes=79/762
Jun 21 12:26:44 domain dovecot: master: Warning: Processes aren't dying after reload, sending SIGTERM.
Jun 21 12:26:44 domain dovecot: config: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1884 uid=0 code=kill)
```

Comment: посмотрите логи в /var/log/ и там либо каталог mail или файлы содержащие mail в названии, а может еще как нибудь, поизучайте содержимое того каталога

Comment: Покажите ваш `/var/log/maillog`

Comment: У Вас в ISPManager для домена везде почему-то указан IP 192.168.1.103. Он же относится к диапазону, зарезервированному для локальных сетей.

Comment: @Streletz так надо. Сервер стоит за роутером.

Comment: Даже если за роутером, почтовый домен создаётся и прописывается у регистратора домена. Инструкции, что Вы читали, скорее всего, написаны из расчёта на виртуальный хостинг или VPS.

Comment: Посмотрите логи. Не исключено, что сервер из-за таких настроек пытается отправить письма совсем не в интернет (это об отправке с сервера). Также было бы не плохо проверить порты в фаерволе сервера и на роутере.

Comment: @Streletz у регистратора домена я прописал внешний IP сервера (то бишь роутера). Там всё нормально. НО! То есть? Почта идёт по другим портам? Чёрт. А если так, то вполне может быть, что я весь день потратил впустую. :(

Comment: в логах поищите упоминания `my.post@gmail.com` т.е. адрес на который вы тестовое письмо отправляли. надо понять было ли оно вообще отправлено. И раз вы за роутером вы снаружи прокинули 25 к себе на сервер ?

Comment: @Mike в логах `maillog` искал сразу же - нет упоминаний. А в логах экзима только что посмотрел. По всей видимости, действительно проблема в портах, так как `T=remote_smtp defer (-53): retry time not reached for any host` и `Connection timed out`. Буду ждать появления онлайн человека, который порты открывал. Сервер, просто, не у меня стоит, и прямого доступа к роутеру я не имею.

Comment: @intro94 А вы попробуйте снаружи постучаться на тот сервер куда MX указывает `telnet ip-addres 25` по крайней мере должны увидеть приглашение почтового сервера. можете ему `HELO domain.com` написать, он ответить должен. Если этого не происходит - либо порт не проброшен, либо сервер не поднят, либо фаервол где то заблочил

Comment: @Mike точняк. Порты на роутере закрыты. Чёрт. :)

Comment: @Mike порты открыл, но всё равно не отправляется/принимается почта. Проверил на telnet - результат записал в текст вопроса, после скриншотов, до логов.

Comment: теперь в логах что то должно появляться по поводу отправки/получения. (imap сообщения которые вы привели к делу вообще не относятся, imap используется для получения почты из ящика и в своих логах ничего интересного обычно не пишет)

Comment: @Mike я чуть ниже результат выполнения команды, только что добавил инфу касательно портов. Кое-что непонятное...

Comment: По-моему, вы недоудаляли свой domain.com из вопроса...

Comment: @nobody да ну блин. Спасибо за инфу. :)

Comment: `***.***.***.140` - это чей адрес?

Comment: @PavelMayorov внешний адрес роутера, за которым стоит сервер.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по логам, ваш сервер не понимает, что письмо пришло локальному получателю и пытается переслать его дальше по цепочке, пересылая его тем самым самому себе.

Иными словами, вот на этой картинке он пытается играть роль MTA хотя должен быть MX. Или, как вариант, он знает что является MX, но не понимает, что MDA - это тоже он.

[image: SMTP transfer mode]

Проверьте конфигурацию сервера - где-то же у него должны быть настройки какие почтовые адреса для него являются локальными, и эти настройки некорректны.

Comment: Я обратился в саппорт ISPmanager. Во-первых, как оказалось, у меня была прописана неверная PTR-запись (стандартная запись от провайдера была). Но даже после исправления почта не заработала. Сейчас саппорт будет смотреть дальше. Отпишусь о результатах позже.

Comment: В общем, ваш ответ был решением одной из проблем. Входящая почта действительно зацикливалась из-за конфигов сервера. Цитата саппорта ISP: `Входящая почта зацикливалась по кругу из-за того, что у вас сервер за NAT'ом. Поправила конфигурационный файл exim /etc/exim/exim.conf, прописав ` **`domainlist dummy_domains mydomain.com`**